# gitignore - now to ignore files but keep child directories

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore all files in a directory but not any children directories and their contents.  For instance ...

```
parentdir
   childdir
      filea
      fileb
   file1
   file2
   file3
```

So, I want to ignore file1, file1, file3 but keep everything else.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a leading `!` to negate a pattern, reincluding any names excluded by previous patterns. This should work:

```
parentdir/*
!parentdir/*/
```

This says to exclude everything inside `parentdir` (but not `parentdir` itself), but then don't exclude any directories -- a trailing slash will match directories but not files.

Comment: Thanks... but either it didn't work or I didn't follow your instructions correctly.  Here's the content of my .gitignore file (I don't know how to format a comment) ... .tmp
.idea
node_modules
!node_modules/.bin/

Comment: @mortsahl You're ignoring `node_modules`; you need to write `node_modules/*` to ignore just its children.

Comment: Thanks again -- still didn't work.  I'm now using `code .tmp
.idea
node_modules/*
!node_modules/.bin/ `  Checked in to new Bitbucket repository, then clone to a new directory.  node_modules was ignored ... but so was node_modules/.bin/

Comment: Got it -- since it was a hidden directory I wanted to not be ignored I had to ` node_modules/.*/ `